# Freezes during scroll in UITableView during parsing JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift, multithreading, uitableview

I'm struggling with multithreading in news app. The thing is - my application freezes often when I scroll table view after data was parsed and loaded and its way too often. I think I'm some kind of wrong of reloading data every time.

First part:

```
final let urlString = "http://api.to.parse"
```

Here I create array of structs to fill in my data

```
struct jsonObjects {
        var id : Int
        var date : String
        var title : String
        var imageURL : URL

    }
    var jsonData = [jsonObjects]()
```

Here's my viewDidLoad of tableView

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // MARK : - Download JSON info on start

    JsonManager.downloadJsonWithURL(urlString: urlString, сompletion: {(jsonArray) -> Void in

        guard let data = jsonArray else { print("Empty dude"); return;}
        for jsonObject in data {

            if let objectsDict = jsonObject as? NSDictionary {

                guard   
                    let id = objectsDict.value(forKey: "id") as? Int,
                    let date = objectsDict.value(forKey: "date") as? String,
                    let titleUnparsed = objectsDict.value(forKey: "title") as? NSDictionary,
                    let title = (titleUnparsed as NSDictionary).value(forKey: "rendered") as? String,
                    let imageString = objectsDict.value(forKey: "featured_image_url") as? String,
                    let imageURL = NSURL(string: imageString) as URL?
                else {
                    print("Error connecting to server")
                    return
                }
```

There I go with appending filled structure to array:

```
                self.jsonData.append(jsonObjects(id: id, date: date, title: title,
                                                 imageURL: imageURL))

            }

        }   
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { 
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    })
```

and downloadJsonWithURL is simply:

```
class JsonManager {

class func downloadJsonWithURL(urlString: String, сompletion: @escaping (NSArray?) -> Void) {

    guard let url = NSURL(string: urlString) else { print("There is no connection to the internet"); return;}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            guard let parseData = data else { print("There is no data"); return;}

                if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: parseData, options: .allowFragments)
        as? NSArray {

                    сompletion(jsonObj)

                }

    }).resume()
}
```

And finally - I input that in my TableViewCell:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return jsonData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newscell") as? NewsTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("Could not find cell by identifier")
    }

    guard let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: jsonData[indexPath.row].imageURL) else {
        fatalError("Could not find image")
    }

        cell.newsTitleLabel.text = self.jsonData[indexPath.row].title
        cell.newsTitleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
        cell.newsImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)

    return cell
}
```

So there are two questions: how should I distribute my threads and how should I call them so that I have smooth and nice tableview with all downloaded data? and how should I reload data in cell?

Comment: Never load data from the Internet on the main queue.

Comment: @rmaddy it seems it doesn't matter whether i add DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async method to parse jsonObject or not. I think all those freezes and lags come from reloadData method but i dunno how to make it work without them

Comment: Don't use `NSData contentsOf:`, it will block execution on that thread (the main thread in this case). Just replace that with regular `NSURLSession` tasks (and double check you still have the right cell once you get the data)

Comment: @jcaron So do i need create one more datatask(withcompletionhandler: inside parsing closure?

Comment: You create one for each image you want to load, yes. And of course you switch back to the main thread before actually assigning the image to the `UIImageView`. Note that if you use a cache library then you won't have the issue, it'll probably do that for you behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the imageData its blocking the main thread. The best way to solve this is to download all the images into an image cache. And I would most certainly remove the downloading of images from within the cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: thank you so much! pre-caching images was the best solution!

Comment: I'm glade I could help

Answer (score 0):

Downloading data, parsing in background thread, the updating the UI on main-thread.

Basically if you do correctly like this, everything will be okay.
So you may need to double check one more time if you are rendering UI on main-thread.

On the debugging panel, there's pause/play button.
So whenever your app frozen, try to pause the app immediately:

1) Then check if any of your UI method is running on background-thread.

2) Check if your downloading task or parsing json doing on main-thread.

If it falls under above cases, it needs to be correct.

Comment: thank you so much, it helped me a lot! too bad i cant choose two answers as right solution